# iOS7 UINavigationController pushViewController:animated back to back with animation locks up the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

From what I can tell, it seems that pushing into `UINavigationController` back to back with animation created a dead lock on iOS7.

I initially struggled with a crash on iOS6 and came up with the solution of:

1. Create an array of view controllers to push onto the navigation controller after the initial push. So if there are three view controllers to be pushed (A, B and C) then this array would have B and C.
2. Implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`'s `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`
3. In the delegate method, simply check if there are more elements in the view controller array. If so, take the first element out of it and push that into the navigation controller.
   So essentially if there are B and C view controllers to be pushed,   `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` will be called three times; every time after the view controller gets pushed starting with A. Obviously, the last call wouldn't do anything since the array should be empty at that point.

Note that this approach worked fine on iOS6. However, this breaks in iOS7. It seems that when it tries to animate in the second push, the app freezes. After digging a little bit more I came up with the solution of pushing the second view controller in the following manner in the delegate implementation.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController 
                                    animated:YES];
});
```

This seems to fix the problem, but I was wondering if anyone has experienced a similar thing and have a better explanation of what exactly is going on.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by these 3 steps? It seems to me, you might be overthinking this. Why don't you simply use navigationController.viewControllers = @[A, B, C] ?

Comment: I should have clarified that I want to animate a sequence of pushes to provide users context of the view hierarchy. So your approach would not exactly yield the same result. Even though my example has three view controllers, my use case is two view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you're having. I created a test app that has a navigation controller and four other controllers. The first controller has a button to push to the second controller, which is FirstPushedViewController. In that controller I have this code to push the next two controllers, and it worked fine in iOS 7:

```
@interface FirstPushedViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *vcs;
@end

@implementation FirstPushedViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    UIViewController *orange = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Orange"];
    UIViewController *red = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Red"];
    self.vcs = [@[red,orange] mutableCopy];
}

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.vcs.count > 0) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vcs.lastObject animated:YES];
        [self.vcs removeLastObject];
    }
}
```